# Add a space in a String after the first letter - Swift 5

Tags: swift

I have a string: `$271.65`, how can I add a space after the `$` in the most native way possible? I'm using SwiftUI

I tried the property `.kerning(10)` but that adds space after each character, I only want after the first one.

Thanks

Comment: What about using a NumberFormatter if it is a currency you are working with?

Comment: You should use a NumberFormatter to properly handle localization like this. Never try to format it yourself, you’re guaranteed to do it wrong.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm working with currency yes, I'm using a function that converts a double to String: `numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currency`

Comment: @Alexander can you post in the answer section how to handle that?

Comment: @Arturo If you're already using `NumberFormatter`, the default settings should generate currency strings that are correctly formatted for the user's locale. In some sense, the correct answer of "how do I add a space after the `$`" is *you don't*, because that wouldn't be the correct format. A number formatter with the correct locale set should add a space for you in places where that's customary.

Comment: @Alexander I know it adds the currency symbol, but it is right next to the amount without a space. I haven't tried but I think the solution from Leo below will work

Comment: @Arturo That's kind of the point. It didn't put a space because it would be incorrect to do so in the current user's locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var greeting = "Hello, playground"
greeting.insert(" ", at: greeting.index(after: greeting.startIndex))
print(greeting) // H ello, playground 
greeting.insert(" ", at: greeting.index(greeting.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))
print(greeting) // H  ello, playground
```

Comment: That worked very nice in a single line, thanks Adrien. Will accept in 4 min

Answer (score 5):

No need to manually add a space to your final string. If you want a space between the dollar sign and the currency value you can simply use a fixed locale "en_US_POSIX". This will make sure the currency format will never be affected by the device's locale and settings.

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
numberFormatter.string(for: 271.65)  // "$ 271.65"
```